# Julia - Possible to tell if a program is running?

Tags: julia

I am trying to only continue my code once a launched application is finished running. This program actively generates a .txt file in parallel to my julia script. My code then needs to read in the completed file. he current problem is that julia is reading in the file that is in progress of being written to. This results in an incomplete data-set.

Currently, I analyzing the file size of the text document inside of a while loop to pause the program unitl the size stops iterating. See below:

```
prevSize = 0
while prevSize != filesize(polarPath)
    sleep(2)
    global prevSize = filesize(polarPath)
end
```

This works fine except the program is not consisten in its writing speed for various input parameters (hence the sloppy `sleep(2)`). This allows time for the program to write for most cases but I am looking for a more elegant solution. I am think that there might be a way to check if the external program has closed (it does so automatically when finished writing the file).

Comment: I would generally suggest using language-agnostic operating system tools for this. [`incron`](https://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en), for example, can be used to start your Julia program whenever a file in a given directory had been open for write and then is closed.

Comment: ...that said, if you want to see a native-Julia inotify client (getting notifications from the filesystem when files it cares about have had watched events take place), take a look at https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl

Comment: Another approach that's well within the bounds of good practice is advisory locking. If the file is `flock`ed with the exclusive bit set while it's being written, and you try to do a `flock` with the shared bit set while you're trying to read it, no reads will happen until a write has finished (and the write lock will automatically be cleared when the program that holds it exits). That's a nicely language-agnostic feature; you can use flock in pretty much any language, including shell scripts (if `util-linux` or another toolkit with a command-line wrapper for the facility is installed).

Comment: I think (if I understood your question correctly) you could also `run` the other program from within Julia using `@async` and then wait `@sync` until the process is completed so you can read it. That is if you have control over the execution of the other program.